# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for (android:id/content)

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

A library we are using, Usabilla:
https://github.com/usabilla/usabilla-u4a-android-sdk/issues/180#

presents a banner fragment at any point in the app, when a certain event occurs.

The only method that we call to trigger the event, is this:
Usabilla.sendEvent(applicationContext,eventString)

It works fine when the activity layout has no fragment tag. But when we include a NavHostFragment in the layout, the app crashes because logger says that the view is null for (android:id/content). Any ideas what we could do to fix the issue (so that even with a NavHostFragment, the android:id/content will still be found)?

Stack trace:

2020-10-29 06:00:05.796 22184-22184/au.com.nib.memberapp.develop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: au.com.nib.memberapp.develop, PID: 22184
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x1020002 (android:id/content) for fragment BannerFragment{32c54c0} (c7b3bbc0-668a-4553-9c52-f031b04f8a83) id=0x1020002}
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:315)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1199)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2181)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2004)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1959)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1861)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)

Comment: Do share your logs

Comment: Done. See editted post.

Comment: Can you share your xml file for the same

Comment: Issue resolved- please see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved our issue above. The problem was with the Usabilla.updateFragmentManager (which needs to be called before Usabilla.sendEvent(applicationContext,eventString)). Before, we used the parentFragmentManager of the current fragment. We switched to activity.supportFragmentManager, and it worked.